# Использовать actionBar в нескольких фрагментах

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-toolbar

В приложении есть несколько фрагментов, которые сменяют друг друга в зависимости от выбранного пункта меню. Также есть toolBar.

1. Как правильно организовать работу с ним? К примеру, на нем есть кнопка поиска и необходимо, чтобы в зависимости от отображаемого фрагмента производился поиск в разных местах. Где обрабатывать это нажатие? Какая переменная содержит информацию о том, какой фрагмент открыт?
2. Где скрывать ненужные пункты меню на toolBar'е при открытии определенных фрагментов, в MainActivity или в коде самого фрагмента? Получалось делать это в MainActivity, но когда пытался получить меню из фрагмента, у меня попросту дублировались пункты. Т.е. вместо двух их стало четыре.

Comment: Создайте отдельные разметки в директории`menu` и для каждого фрагмента в котором реализован метод `onCreateOptionMenu` подключайте нужную разметку

Comment: @McDaggen подключать разметку нужно в коде активити, в котором располагается фрагмент, или в самом фрагменте?

Comment: В самом фрагменте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653737/oncreateoptionsmenu-inside-fragments

Comment: @McDaggen а можно ли будет в этом случае использовать одну и ту же разметку для нескольких фрагментов и обрабатывать нажатия на один и тот же пункт меню в разных фрагментах по-разному?